# Что значит неявное преобразование типов с помощью operator=?

Tags: c++, терминология, преобразование-типов

Что означает фраза, что неявные преобразования для экземпляров некоторого пользовательского класса могут осуществляться (помимо не-explicit конструкторов и операторов преобразования) посредством оператора присваивания? Что тут неявного? Т.е. мы пишем `a = b`, где `a` имеет тип `A`, а `b` какой-то другой тип `B`, при этом мы же явно пишем знак `=`, указывая тем самым, что вызывается такой-то оператор, который запишет этот `b` в наш экземпляр. С не-explicit к-рами все понятно: вызываем какую-то функцию `void f(A)` в виде `f(b)` - вот понятно, что неявно вызывается какой-то к-р, мы и не пишем никаких дополнительных символов. Вопрос произошел [отсюда](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/), см. Implicit conversions with classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языках С и С++ есть понятие *явного* преобразования типа: явным преобразованием типа называется преобразование сделанное при помощи явно использованных пользователем операторов приведения типа - "кастов". Примеры явных преобразований типов в С++

```
double d = 3.14;
int a = (int) d;         // Каст в стиле С
a = int(d);              // Каст в функциональной нотации
a = static_cast<int>(d); // С++ каст `static_cast`
```

Преобразование типа, сделанное без явно указанного каста, называется *неявным*.

Сам акт *встроенного* присваивания не может делать никакого преобразования типов. Чтобы занести значение в объект `a` типа `A` это значение само должно иметь тип `A`. Без вариантов. А при несовпадении типов левой и правой части в присваивании сначала делается *неявное* преобразование типа правого значения к типу левой части, а только затем выполняется собственно присваивание.

Вам никто не запрещает определить *пользовательский* оператор присваивания, у которого в правой части будет какой угодно тип. Можно будет неформального говорить, что такой оператор присваивания выполняет преобразование типа. Но в отсутствие каста и это преобразование будет называться *неявным*.

---

А если подходить с точки зрения "Что тут неявного?", то тогда в С и С++ программах практически все придется назвать "явным", ибо внимательному глазу все должно быть "явно видно". Но терминология языков С и С++ подходит к вопросу не с этой точки зрения.